# Hide and Show Multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show different divs when each one is clicked... But currently only the first div changes correctly when clicked and the others do nothing when i clicked them.

Current Code:  http://jsfiddle.net/c5VG5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#liked').on('click', function() {$('#liked').hide();$('#notliked').show();});$('#notliked').on('click', function() {$('#liked').show();$('#notliked').hide();});
});

<div id='liked' style='float:left;display:none; height:100px; width:100px; background-color:blue'>1</div><div id='notliked' style='float:left;height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red'>2</div>
<div id='liked' style='float:left;display:none; height:100px; width:100px; background-color:blue'>1</div><div id='notliked' style='float:left;height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red'>2</div>
<div id='liked' style='float:left;display:none; height:100px; width:100px; background-color:blue'>1</div><div id='notliked' style='float:left;height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red'>2</div>
<div id='liked' style='float:left;display:none; height:100px; width:100px; background-color:blue'>1</div><div id='notliked' style='float:left;height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red'>2</div>
```

Comment: `id`s must be unique - that seems to be your problem. Use classes instead.

Comment: This is invalid markup. same id used multiple times for different elements.

Comment: Classes would surely be better. Now I'd just .each them. $('#liked).each(function(){$(this).hide();}); etc.. the same for not liked and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have posted is invalid markup. You just cannot use same id again and again for different elements in a single page, so workaround is this you can change your div's attribute `id` to `class` instead:

```
<div class='liked' ......></div><div class='notliked' ......></div>
<div class='liked' ......></div><div class='notliked' ......></div>    
<div class='liked' ......></div><div class='notliked' ......></div>
```

then you can do this with class selector of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.liked').on('click', function() {
       $(this).hide().next().show();
    });
    $('.notliked').on('click', function() {
       $(this).hide().prev().show();
    });
});
```

---

As per your comment: *didnt want all of them to change at the same time when clicked.*

so for this you have to get the element in the selector's context with `$(this)` and you have to use `.next()` for next element and `.prev()` for previous element.

Comment: sorry didnt want all of them to change at the same time when clicked. wanted each seperate div to change when clicked

Comment: then you can use `$(this)` for current context of selector.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but you can try in this way.
Set one parrent div for  like and dislike, and use it  to show one and hide other.

Javascript

```
$(".clickMe").on('click',function() {
      that  = $(this);
if(that.find("div.like").is(':visible')) {
      that.find("div.like").hide();
      that.find("div.dislike").show();
} else{
      that.find("div.like").show();
      that.find("div.dislike").hide();
}

});
```

Html

```
<div class="clickMe"><div class="like"></div><div class="dislike"></div>
<div class="clickMe"><div class="like"></div><div class="dislike"></div>
<div class="clickMe"><div class="like"></div><div class="dislike"></div>
```